# Spark Broadcast results in increased size of dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe of 1 integer column made of 1B rows. So ideally, the size of the dataframe should be 1B * 4 bytes ~= 4GB. This is proven to be correct when I cache the dataframe and check the size. The size is around 4GB.

Now, if I try to broadcast the same dataframe to join with another dataframe, I get an error: `Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot broadcast the table that is larger than 8GB: 14 GB`

Why does the size of a broadcasted dataframe increase? I have seen this in other cases as well where a 300MB dataframe shows up as 3GB broadcasted dataframe in Spark UI SQL tab.

Any reasoning or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The size increases in memory, if dataframe was broadcasted across your cluster. How much it will increase depends on how many workers you have, because Spark needs to copy your dataframe on every worker to deal with your next operations.

Do not broadcast big dataframes, only small ones, to use in join operations.

As per [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/broadcast/Broadcast.html#:%7E:text=Broadcast%20variables%20allow%20the%20programmer%20to%20keep%20a%20read%2Donly%20variable%20cached%20on%20each%20machine%20rather%20than%20shipping%20a%20copy%20of%20it%20with%20tasks):

*Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks.*

Comment: I doubt this is correct.

Comment: I understand your suggestion to not broadcast big dataframes and I agree with it. But why do you think size would change on broadcast? I have nearly 150 workers and the error message size is no where close to 4GB*150. Ideally the dataframe should get collected in the master node and then broadcasted to all workers and hence I don't think this should increase the size. Do let me know what you think.

Comment: Can you please say where your workers are situated? If only one machine handles 150 workers, so I guess you're using only the same ram. 
As far as I know, Master-node doesn't do anything with data, but orchestrate all workers and tell them to copy your dataframe on each worker for broadcast.

Lastly, you can show us some of your code, if it's not very very simple

Answer (score 1):

More so an error according to this post. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-37321

Comment: Thank you for this. The above bug is sort of opposite of my issue where the size is being estimated way lesser than actual size resulting in spark implicitly planning a broadcast join. But underlying issue might be the same(incorrect size estimation).

Comment: I am pretty sure I am correct.